# ticks and labels of right y-axis of ax.twinx().twiny() not removable

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to combine a plot of a lot of data, that takes several seconds and combine it with a plot of very little data that is plotted in the same frame of reference as the former plot. The latter is plotted interactively. In the following MWE the interactive part is simulated by a loop.

My problem is that when I clone the original axes with `twinx().twiny()` I cannot get rid of the ticks for both of the axes of the twined axes object.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import choice
from time import sleep
%matplotlib notebook


data = np.random.rand(100,2)*10

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax1.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1])
ax2 = ax1.twinx().twiny()

ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.tick_params(top=False, labeltop=False, left=False, labelleft=False, right=False, labelright=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

for i in range(10):
    try:
        sc.remove()
    except:
        pass
    p = choice(data)
    sc = ax2.scatter(p[0], p[1], s=10, color='red')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    sleep(.5)

plt.show()
```

So `ax2.tick_params(top=False, labeltop=False, left=False, labelleft=False, right=False, labelright=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)` should get rid of any ticks and labels, right? But is doesn't. The plot looks like this:

[image]

The right y-axis should not be there, should it? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that you have 3 axes. `ax1`, `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` and `ax3 = ax2.twiny()`. You're doing `ax3 = ax1.twinx().twiny()`, so you do not have any handle to `ax2` stored anywhere so you cannot change its ticks.

Comment: However, I do not understand the reason to use twin axes if they have the same scale than the original ones. Just remove those and plot everything in the same axes.

Comment: Ah, that's weird. Shouldn’t objects without any references be cleared up by garbage collection? I guess that third axes is registered somewhere in internal matplotlib logic?

Comment: Sure, I mean `ax.twinx()` directly adds the axes to the figure. And the figure should not loose any of its axes, just because you forgot to pass some handle around, right? Besides, what should the twiny of the twinx refer to if the twinx got deleted in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution worked on my code (below) and I just called the params before the actual plot.

```
ax2 = axes[ax].twiny()
ax2.tick_params(top=False, labeltop=False, left=False, labelleft=False, right=False, labelright=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
ax2.plot(x, vals[ax], color = 'black')
```

You can probably make it work if you figure out the placement of the line.